# C reading/printing words from files using strdup(), etc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

C beginner here, I was given a homework assignment where we are to use gedit to design a program to read in file names from the command line and by designing a getNextWord method. We are to simply open each file one at and time and return the words, ignoring everything but alphanumeric characters (and converting uppercase letters to lower). The thing I'm hung up on is that my instructor gave us the strdup() function to help us out as well as isspace, alnum, etc. Anyways, after looking up strdup() on this site as well as C basics and the site and others there must be something I'm not understanding. My program compiles (I use gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 words.c -o words) and it compiles with just a warning that strdup() is implicitly used. running the program with a few text files in the same directory has it print gobbly gook as if its running off the bounds of the heap, then giving a segmentation fault(core dump). I thought I was also giving it the right checks, such as putting \0 at the end of the character array before return strdup of the pointer, etc. Here is my code; I'm not expecting anyone to do my hw for me, maybe an observation would help as I have researched all day and cant find the problem. Thanks for reading this (its not showing but i included stdio, stdlib.h, string.h, ctype.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 256


char* getNextWord(FILE* fd)
{

    int index = 0;
    int c;

    char str[MAX_WORD_SIZE];

    while((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF){

        c = fgetc(fd);

        if (isspace(c)){
            str[index] = '\0';
            return (char*) strdup(str);
        }

        if (((index+1) != (MAX_WORD_SIZE-1)) && (isalnum(c))){
            c = tolower(c);
            str[index] = c;
            index++;
        }
        else {
            index++;
            str[index] = '\0';
            return (char*) strdup(str);
        }

    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char** current = argv;
    char* heapedString = NULL;

    while (*current)
    {
        char* filename = *current;
        FILE* fd = fopen(filename, "r");
        if (fd == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"can't read the file\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        while ((heapedString = getNextWord(fd)) != NULL)
        {
            heapedString = getNextWord(fd);
            printf("%s\n", heapedString);
            free(heapedString);         
        }   
        fclose(fd);
        current++;  

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's because you're discarding every other character and word. You have the same kind of error in both whiles:

```
while((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF){

    c = fgetc(fd);

    ....
}
```

You should just call fgetc (or getNextWord) once each loop. You should do either this:

```
while((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF){
    ....
}
```

Or this:

```
while(1){
    c = fgetc(fd);
    if (c == EOF) break;
    ....
}
```

But not a combination of both

Answer (score 3):

It's just a hunch, but I believe the following two lines are the cause of the error.

```
while((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF){
c = fgetc(fd);
```

The internal file position indicator is advanced to the next character on each use.  So it's being advanced on call of the while loop.  This is probably messing up your desired result.

Look at the code found here, and notice that a do while is used instead.  Good luck!
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/

Answer (score 1):

You're calling fgetc twice in each iteration - once in a while () condition and right after. You also make the same mistake when calling getNextWord.

Answer (score 1):

As for the implicit declaration of `strdup` part of the question: `strdup`, like many other commonly used functions, is not a part of the C99 standard library. If you take a look at `man strdup` and check the "Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc" part, you'll see what you'll have to `#define` before including the library. For example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *foo = "foo";
    char *bar = strdup(foo);
    puts(bar);
    free(bar);
}
```

You'll come across this if you want to use POSIX features and at the same time use the -std=c99 option to stay as ISO C99 compliant as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Minor issue but why are you using

```
if (((index+1) != (MAX_WORD_SIZE-1)) && (isalnum(c)))
```

as your check? removing the +1 from index should suffice, I think. For my code for this assignment I'm using

```
if ( isalnum( c ) && ( j <= ( MAX_WORD_SIZE - 1 ) ) )
```

and it works precisely as required by the assignment AFAICT (obviously I have j as my 'index' and the order is irrelevant)

You'll want to add a check in main to see if heapedString[0] == '\0' as well, or you're going to get a lot of empty lines printed. While this might still satisfy the assignment, it's probably better to not have them printing out.